# Is there a way to check if an int not equal to all values in an array? (C++)

Tags: c++, arrays

I know there is a way to check if a value is in an array, but is there a way to 
check if a value is not?

This code will check through every index but will ignore the past indexes when it goes on to the next one.
(i.e. Is there a code that checks that vary_result!= "all values in array"?)

```
int buffer; //all variables
int vary_result;
int range;
int minimum_value;
for(int j = 0; j < buffer; j++) {
    if(vary_result == buffer_array[j]){
        vary_result = rand() % range + minimum_value; // creates a random value and saves it at vary_result
        };
    };
cout << vary_result << endl;
```

Comment: What's the point of `vary_result = rand() % range + minimum_value;`? That doesn't seem to have anything to do with the stated goal

Comment: check if the value is in the array, call the result `x` then the check if it is not in the array is `!x`.

Comment: [`std::none_off`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/all_any_none_of)

Answer (score 4):

> I know there is a way to check if a value is in an array, but is there a way to check if a value is not?

Second is just opposite to the first:

```
auto begin = buffer_array;
auto end   = buffer_array + buffer;
auto it = std::find(begin, end, value );
if( it == end ) // value not found which means none of the elements equal to value, which means value is not in array
    // do whatever, but do not dereference it
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes there is a way to test if a value is not in an array. Here is how I did it:

```
 bool valueInArray;
 bool valueNotInArray = true;
 int valueToTest = 10;
 int valuesArray[] = [1, 2, 3, 5, 9];


 for(int i = valuesArray.length(); i <= valuesArray.length(); i++) {
 if(valueToTest == valuesArray[i]) 
    notInIt == false;
 }

 if (notInIt == false) 
    valueInArray = true;
 else
    valueInArray = false;
```

Essentially, I created two booleans, a number to test, and an array. I went through the array with a for loop to test if the number was in the array. Then, I used a if/else to set the other boolean opposite of previous one. In this way, the final boolean reflects if the value is not in the array.

Comment: Your code has a problem, let's say if the second last value of the array was equal to the test value, notInIt would be false. However, if the last value of the array was not equal to the test value, notIntIt would be true. Hence, it would seem that the test variable was not in the array even though it was.